# With the destruction of Album Archives, where will all of the photos from a Hangouts be stored?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I have received many notifications from Google saying that [Album Archives](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/) and [Google+](http://plus.google.com) are going away as no one is really using them. In this case, where will all of the new photos from Google Hangouts be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't really announced, yet. As per the latest news, you are supposed to back up all your photos and videos either via **[Album Archive](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/)** or via **[Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout)**. Google Hangouts is slowly getting "discontinued" as well. In the 1st phase, this will happen for all G Suit users and the 2nd phase will be rolled out for the rest of the users. Eventually will be Google Hangouts replaced by **Hangouts Chat** and **Hangouts Meet** including a few of current futures and **[bunch of new ones](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7651799)**.

- more here: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126361/186471**
- and here: **[https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/upcoming-hangouts](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/upcoming-hangouts-service-consolidation.html)**

Comment: So is album archive still going to exist, and if not, what is its replacement? Or has that also not been released yet?

Comment: album archive should remain without changes

Comment: oh okay. I had read the banner wrong